# Module name for angular jwt in angular 6

Tags: angular

I used the **npm install angular2-jwt** but this is not working with angular 6, getting compilation error  /node_modules/rxjs/Observable"' has no exported member 'Observable' in the /node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.js .

Answer (score 1):

You need to import it like this,

```
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

and in your service,

```
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

Answer (score 1):

For angular 6 install [@auth0/angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt) instead of `angular2-jwt`.

Use `npm i @auth0/angular-jwt`  for more details refer the [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt).